# Solve the Logarithmic equation in $[0 \:\: 2\pi]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, logarithms

Find number of solutions of the Logarithmic equation in $[0 \:\: 2\pi]$

$$\log_{\sqrt{5}}\left(\tan x\right)+ \log_{\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{\log_{\tan x}(5\sqrt{5})+\log_{\sqrt{5}}(5\sqrt{5})}=-\sqrt{6}$$

i first simplified $${\log_{\tan x}(5\sqrt{5})+\log_{\sqrt{5}}(5\sqrt{5})}=\frac{3}{2}\log_{\tan x}5+3$$  and also

$$\log_{\sqrt{5}}(\tan x)=2\log_{5}(\tan x)$$

Letting $a=\log_{\tan x}5$  The given equation reduces to

$$2a+\log_{5}\left(\frac{3}{2}a+3\right)=-\sqrt{6}$$

can i know how to proceed further?

Comment: i think there are four Solutions in the given interval, from where Comes this probelm?